# How to delete from a related table if a certain field gets updated in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

If an update of table `LandContract` means that the value of field `LandContract.PriceType` changes from "Fast årspris" to "Rörligt årspris", I want to delete from table `LandContractAnnualPrice` where `LandContractAnnualPrice.LandContractId` = `LandContractId.Id`.

I know how to do this in PHP, but is it preferred to put this kind of logic in a MySQL trigger? If so, then how should I define such trigger?

Below is my attempt at creating the trigger. It's the first time I write one so I don't dare to try it :) Will it do what I want?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER delete_from_related_table AFTER UPDATE
 ON LandContract
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  IF (OLD.PriceType = 'Rörligt årspris' AND NEW.PriceType = 'Fast årspris') THEN
   DELETE FROM LandContractAnnualPrice WHERE LandContractId = OLD.Id;
   END IF;
 END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I prefer you should try first , If its not working then you have to ask.

Comment: @VinayHegde Omg, I will probably delete the whole database. But okay, I'll try it!

Comment: Why you want to delete a whole database create a two dummy table with the exact schema and try it by inserting and updating the table. Just to make sure your trigger working, Once starts working as expected drop those 2 dummy table and use it with a real db table.

Comment: @VinayHegde Dude, that totally worked! I was **not** expecting that. Is it better to put this logic in a trigger or in PHP?

Comment: @VinayHegde Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYTRIGGER 
AFTER UPDATE ON LandContract
REFERENCING NEW AS newRow OLD AS oldRow
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  IF (oldRow.PriceType = 'Rörligt årspris' AND newRow .PriceType = 'Fast årspris') THEN
     DELETE FROM LandContractAnnualPrice WHERE LandContractId = oldRow.Id;
  END IF;
END MYTRIGGER;
```